# iOS - AVPlayer seekToTime restarts playback of currentItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, avplayer

I'm making an app that uses AVPlayer. In one of my views I have a UISlider with which the user should be able to scrub forward and backward. I'm having some trouble getting `seekToTime` to work as I want. When I try to change time the playback starts from 0, and I'm not sure how to solve this. My current implementation looks like this:

```
[self.progressSlider  addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderValueChanged) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

[self.progressSlider  addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderReleased) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


- (void)sliderValueChanged {

    [...]
    [player pause];

}

- (void)sliderReleased {

    float timeInSecond = self.progressSlider.value;

    timeInSecond *= 1000;

    // I have trie to hard code this value, but I get the same result.
    CMTime cmTime = CMTimeMake(timeInSecond, NSEC_PER_SEC);

    [player.currentItem seekToTime:cmTime toleranceBefore:kCMTimeZero toleranceAfter:kCMTimeZero completionHandler:^(BOOL finished) {

        if (finished) {
            [player play];
        }
    }];
}
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Can mention that I stream audio using AVPlayer's: `playerItemWithURL` if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that `NSEC_PER_SEC` is 1,000,000,000, so `CMTimeMake(timeInSecond, NSEC_PER_SEC)` is going to be a really tiny number (unless `timeInSecond` is ridiculously huge) - in fact, it will be arbitrarily close to zero, which is exactly what you are experiencing.

Just to be clear: `CMTimeMake` defines a rational number. You are giving a numerator and a denominator. If your denominator is huge, the rational number will be tiny.

Comment: Thanks, tried to change it to something smaller, like 1. And it seems to work. The scrubbing isn't very precise with this number though. Could you give a recommendation on what value to use? Or should I do something else to make it more precise?

Comment: What I would do is call `CMTimeMakeWithSeconds`. The first argument is a float, which is the _actual number of seconds_ (possibly fractional, of course); the second argument is the degree of fineness, which should usually be 600, since that is enough to get you to level of a single frame. The call then does the math for you.

Comment: So, let's say you want to seek to 10.5 seconds. Then `CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(10.5,600)` is as exact as you can get. Alternatively, since CMTimeMake takes only integers, you would have to say something like `CMTimeMake(21,2)` (because 21/2 is 10.5, don't you see).