# After seeking in AVPlayer, I get a negative start time

Tags: objective-c, ios7, avplayer

I have a video that is about 40 minutes long. I need to be able to seek to a specific time and get a consistent frame, but when I seek through the video, the timeline gets offset every so often and the frame no longer matches.

```
AVPlayerItem* currentItem = avPlayer.currentItem;
NSArray* seekableRanges = currentItem.seekableTimeRanges;
if (seekableRanges.count > 0)
{
    CMTimeRange range = [[seekableRanges objectAtIndex:0] CMTimeRangeValue];
    startTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(range.start);
}
```

When I NSLog the startTime as the video plays, it starts off at 0 and then, after some seeking, it will start returning -1.xxxx and then after some more seeking -2.xxxxx.

Any ideas on how to fix it? I'm not modifying the currentItem anywhere, just seeking through it.

Comment: Why are you doing this with `seekableTimeRanges`? After all, nothing is guaranteed about what kind of result it will return. If you want to seek to a specific CMTime, why don't you just specify it and seek to it?

Comment: Is the problem that you don't know how to make a CMTime? If so, see my answer (and comments) here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23229197/341994

Comment: Well the problem is that when I try to seek to a specific CMTime, it is inconsistent because there is a time offset that was somehow introduced in the currentItem. The problem is that I have a specific time saved on a server that I need to seek to, but the local video has inconsistent time offsets depending on how much scrubbing has happened.

Comment: Before I believe that, I'd need to see the code you tried to use to set the specific CMTime.

Comment: @matt what do you mean by "Why are you doing this with seekableTimeRanges? After all, nothing is guaranteed about what kind of result it will return", is `seekableTimeRanges` not reliable ?

Comment: @onmyway133 It isn't a question of reliability. It's a question of how `seekableTimeRanges` expresses itself. The OP seems to be assuming that the start of the first range in `seekableTimeRanges` will always be zero and is then surprised when that's not the case. But there was no reason to assume that in the first place. If the goal is to move the playhead to 0 the OP should move the playhead to 0, and not make assumptions in advance about what the `seekableTimeRanges` will be.

Comment: @matt agree, but moving the playhead should take seekableTimeRanges into account, because there will be live stream with limited sliding window, at that time seekableTimeRanges startTime will not be 0

Comment: @onmyway133 Fine. But we don't know that this is a streaming video. In any case, if you think you've got an answer to the OP's question, please do answer it!