# AVPlayer seekToTime causes the player to stop playing

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, avplayer

I have an AVPlayer that streams a radio station and has a rewind button I built. When you rewind, the method is called and WORKS about 80% of the time, successfully setting the current time of the AVPLayer back X-many seconds. However, the other 20% of the time, the AVPlayer stops playing audio and will not play it again until the app is killed and reopened. Here is the method:

```
- (IBAction)rewind:(id)sender
{
    CMTime cmTime = CMTimeMake(CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player.currentTime) - 1.0, 1);
    CMTime almostZero = CMTimeMake(1, 2);
    if (CMTimeGetSeconds(cmTime) > CMTimeGetSeconds(almostZero)) {
    [self.player.currentItem seekToTime:cmTime];
    }
}
```

For context, it is a live stream.

Here is my 15-second rewind method:

```
 if((self.currentPlaybackTime - 15.0f) > CMTimeGetSeconds(kCMTimeZero)) {
        [self.player pause];
        [self.player seekToTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds((self.currentPlaybackTime - 15.0f), self.player.currentTime.timescale)];
        [self.player play];
        } else if((self.currentPlaybackTime - 10.0f) > CMTimeGetSeconds(kCMTimeZero)) {
       [self.player pause];
       [self.player seekToTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds((self.currentPlaybackTime - 10.0f), self.player.currentTime.timescale)];
            [self.player play];
    } else if((self.currentPlaybackTime - 5.0f) > CMTimeGetSeconds(kCMTimeZero)) {
        [self.player pause];
        [self.player seekToTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds((self.currentPlaybackTime - 5.0f), self.player.currentTime.timescale)];
        [self.player play];

    } else if((self.currentPlaybackTime - 3.0f) > CMTimeGetSeconds(kCMTimeZero)) {
        [self.player pause];
        [self.player seekToTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds((self.currentPlaybackTime - 3.0f), self.player.currentTime.timescale)];
        [self.player play];
    } else if((self.currentPlaybackTime - 2.0f) > CMTimeGetSeconds(kCMTimeZero)) {
       [self.player pause];
       [self.player seekToTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds((self.currentPlaybackTime - 2.0f), self.player.currentTime.timescale)];
        [self.player play];
    } else if((self.currentPlaybackTime - 1.0f) > CMTimeGetSeconds(kCMTimeZero)) {
        [self.player pause];
        [self.player seekToTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds((self.currentPlaybackTime - 1.0f), self.player.currentTime.timescale)];
        [self.player play];
    }

- (NSTimeInterval)currentPlaybackTime
{
    return CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player.currentTime);
}
```

When I logged the method and seconds, you can see that on the third rewind (on which the audio always stops and won't restart), the player didn't actually go back 15 seconds, although it seems the seekToTime to the current time minus 15 seconds worked.

```
2015-05-28 09:34:57.383 Lancers[78554:11732524] sec: 45
2015-05-28 09:34:58.382 Lancers[78554:11732524] sec: 46
2015-05-28 09:34:59.383 Lancers[78554:11732524] sec: 47
2015-05-28 09:35:00.383 Lancers[78554:11732524] sec: 48
2015-05-28 09:35:01.382 Lancers[78554:11732524] sec: 49
2015-05-28 09:35:02.237 Lancers[78554:11732524] CURRENT PLAYING TIME: 49.855237
2015-05-28 09:35:02.237 Lancers[78554:11732524] REWIND 15 SECONDS!
2015-05-28 09:35:02.293 Lancers[78554:11732524] sec: 35
2015-05-28 09:35:02.293 Lancers[78554:11732524] sec: 35
2015-05-28 09:35:02.305 Lancers[78554:11732524] sec: 35
2015-05-28 09:35:02.305 Lancers[78554:11732524] sec: 35
2015-05-28 09:35:02.305 Lancers[78554:11732524] sec: 35
2015-05-28 09:35:02.472 Lancers[78554:11732524] sec: 35
2015-05-28 09:35:03.472 Lancers[78554:11732524] sec: 36
2015-05-28 09:35:04.473 Lancers[78554:11732524] sec: 37
2015-05-28 09:35:05.473 Lancers[78554:11732524] sec: 38
2015-05-28 09:35:06.473 Lancers[78554:11732524] sec: 39
2015-05-28 09:35:07.472 Lancers[78554:11732524] sec: 40
2015-05-28 09:35:08.473 Lancers[78554:11732524] sec: 41
2015-05-28 09:35:09.473 Lancers[78554:11732524] sec: 42
2015-05-28 09:35:10.473 Lancers[78554:11732524] sec: 43
2015-05-28 09:35:11.472 Lancers[78554:11732524] sec: 44
2015-05-28 09:35:12.472 Lancers[78554:11732524] sec: 45
2015-05-28 09:35:13.472 Lancers[78554:11732524] sec: 46
2015-05-28 09:35:13.771 Lancers[78554:11732524] CURRENT PLAYING TIME: 46.299634
2015-05-28 09:35:13.771 Lancers[78554:11732524] REWIND 15 SECONDS!
2015-05-28 09:35:13.821 Lancers[78554:11732524] sec: 31
2015-05-28 09:35:13.821 Lancers[78554:11732524] sec: 31
2015-05-28 09:35:13.833 Lancers[78554:11732524] sec: 31
2015-05-28 09:35:13.833 Lancers[78554:11732524] sec: 31
2015-05-28 09:35:13.833 Lancers[78554:11732524] sec: 31
2015-05-28 09:35:14.557 Lancers[78554:11732524] sec: 32
2015-05-28 09:35:15.557 Lancers[78554:11732524] sec: 33
2015-05-28 09:35:16.556 Lancers[78554:11732524] sec: 34
2015-05-28 09:35:16.870 Lancers[78554:11732524] CURRENT PLAYING TIME: 34.314164
2015-05-28 09:35:16.870 Lancers[78554:11732524] REWIND 15 SECONDS!
2015-05-28 09:35:16.898 Lancers[78554:11732524] sec: 34
2015-05-28 09:35:16.899 Lancers[78554:11732524] sec: 34
```

Comment: If you have an approach that works, what's the question?

Comment: It doesn't. The rewind button works twice, then freezes the audio. You can only rewind 30 seconds, then the player freezes. If I tell the rewind2 method to simply call the rewind1 method 15 times, the player still freezes on the third call.

Comment: I'm unclear what "freezes" means. If you want to resume play after seeking, does it help if you call `seekToTime:toleranceBefore:toleranceAfter:completionHandler:` instead? The whole point of the `completionHandler:` is so that you can do something like play after seeking.

Comment: Thank you. What should I set the tolerance to? When I seek with the rewind1 method it continues playing, so I figured it always continues playing after you seek.

Comment: I don't know, but the docs say that that is the most accurate. I'm not saying this will work, but if would sure be nice if it does! Give it a shot and let's see what happens...

Comment: Also, I'm a little confused by your code; do you understand how CMTimeMake works? It may be that you are just giving invalid times. See my discussion here http://stackoverflow.com/a/23229197/341994 (and be sure to look at both my answer and my comments below it).

Comment: If you're still interested, see the update in my question. It seems using `seekToTime:toleranceBefore:toleranceAfter:completionHandler:` instead didn't work either.

Comment: I'm also pretty sure my times are valid. The method works correctly twice (goes to the proper CMTime, which is the current time minus 15 seconds), then always on the third time the player stops playing, and nothing will get it to play again. If the times are invalid, why would it work twice then fail?

Answer (score 2):

I'm making a guess about your app, but I think the problem could be in the buffering of your streaming audio.  I've used AVPlayer a bunch of times with local media and have never had any issues with seekToTime.

Leaping to an invalid time would mess you up, but from what I can see in your code you should be OK. Your rewind code is trying to move back 1 second (not 15?) unless you are within 1/2 second of the start in which case you don't seek and continue to play.

I would check the status of the AVPlayer object (player.status, player.error) in the rewind method and see what is happening when you call seekToTime. Also check the value and state flags of your cmTime variable with the debugger or NSLog just to be sure you are good there too.

Comment: I have two separate rewind methods, one that does 15 and another for 1 second. I haven't used AVPlayer before so I'm not entirely sure how to implement your suggestion, but I appreciate it nonetheless and will try my best.

Something as simple as this should work, no?

 `NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", self.player.error);
  NSLog(@"STATUS: %d", self.player.status);`

Comment: Hmm I got Error = NULL and Status = 1, no matter whether it rewinded successfully or caused the player to stop playing. The button still works even after the player stops playing, in which case I still got error = NULL and status = 1.

Comment: OK. Eliminating possible problems. Yes, you are logging correctly.  What about @matt 's suggestion to look at the values of cmTime in the method. Maybe it is going wacky after the second calculation of cmTime. Can you post the code for the -15 second adjustment so we can see the executing code that is giving you the problem?  thx - dcl

Comment: OK, I've posted the 15-second rewind method. It basically rewinds just like the above method, except with a bunch of if-clauses so that it will rewind back to 0 or 1 if you have a current time less than 15 seconds.

Comment: OK. Here's what I think is happening. Unfortunately if I'm right, your code should never work. That it works sometimes may be just the timing of how AVPlayer works internally. AVPlayer.currentTime only returns the current time if you are playing. If stopped, then currentTime returns the start time for the media. So after you call [self.player pause] the value you get back from currentPlaybackTime isn't what you think. Save currentTime before you pause and do the seekToTime calculation with that value.

Comment: I never really see programs with the ability to rewind a live stream--do you think this is why? And oddly enough, when I delete the `[self.player pause]` as well as the `[self.player play]` surrounding the `seekToTime:` method, absolutely nothing changes. Do you think there is absolutely no way to accomplish this? Fortunately I've solved the fastforwarding problem by creating a singleton of NSDate that tracks accurately how long the player has been streaming, but this rewind function has been occupying me for almost a solid week.

Comment: I'm sure you'll be able to do it. So long as you are keeping the streaming data in a buffer somewhere the to the AVPlayer it isn't really streaming.

Comment: Can you suggest any links about how I could best do that? Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you already have the data coming into your app and playing--which is a big step. Consider what that data is and where it is flowing through your app. With that you can figure out the best place to cache it, how much you want to keep and for how long. That should then dictate whether you save it to a local file, core data, etc.